# How to update state from the components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on the "Orders list" page.

I have a hook:
`const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])`

What happens currently:

- when page is loaded - I fetch orders with Apollo `useQuery`
- in the `useEffect`: once I get orders, I set them with `setOrders`
- then, I return them with:

```
{orders.map((order) => (
  <OrderComponent order={order}/>
))}
```

This works fine for displaying data, but I would like to be able to change order data (just state) from `OrderComponent`.

So let's say we have a notes input in the OrderComponent:

`<input type="text" name="order_notes" value={order.notes}/>`

The question is:
**How to handle such updates from the child component?**

What I tried:

- On the parent page, I created handler:

```
  const handleOrderNotes = ({ value, orderIndex }) => {
    const ordersCopy = [...orders]
    ordersCopy[ordersIndex].notes = value
    setOrders(ordersCopy)
  }
```

then I passed it to the `OrderComponent` along with `orderIndex`:

```
{orders.map((order, index) => (
  <OrderComponent order={order} orderIndex={index} handleOrderNotes={handleOrderNotes}/>
))}
```

And added the handler to the input:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="order_notes"
  value={order.notes}
  onChange={(value) => { 
    handleOrderNotes({value, orderIndex})
  }}
/>
```

And it worked just fine. But after I started adding more and more stuff, to the point where I would like to use components in `OrderComponent`. I started to wonder if there is a better way of doing such things?

During the devlopment I was often getting errors like:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

So I believe that I'm missing something crucial here.

Just getting started with React, so would apprentice any input. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks good. The only thing use [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in `orders.map`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev There is no better way of doing this? At this point I pass 10+ functions to my `OrderComponent` and it becomes a bit tricky to wrap my head around the entire code.

Comment: I did not understand on the question that this problem arises :) It can be solved by passing 1 function that will additionally accept the key of the object's field being updated. Example: `const handleChange = ({ value, orderIndex, key }) => ... ordersCopy[ordersIndex][key] = value; ...`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev - I have more than simple form; I have couple buttons, selects etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to solve this. You would have to chose which one suits you based on how your app is organized/designed.

1. If using redux or some kind of state management for app, then you don't need to tell parent component but as you have index of the order with you in the child component itself, you can simply update that order in the app store/state itself.
2. You may want to wrap each component with `useMemo` and use `useCallback` for passing any callback to these child components. This second step you should do even if you are have state management done for your app to avoid unnecessary re-renders

Answer (score -2):

Please change this
`{orders.map((order, index) => ( <OrderComponent order={order} orderIndex={index} handleOrderNotes={handleOrderNotes}/> ))}`

to

`{orders.map((order, index) => ( <OrderComponent order={order} orderIndex={index} handleOrderNotes={({value,index})=>handleOrderNotes({value,index})}/> ))}`

Comment: Why are you suggesting creating a wrapper function that does nothing?

Comment: It's arrow function. It will create new function every time and prevents calling function when map executes. [Passing function as props to component](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)